# SO answer: did I CW it?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I wonder how that happened [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864835) has become a CW. I suppose this might be a result of my intensive editing. I would be happier with 3 votes I got after the answer autoCWed. :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this community wiki [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) on meta

> The post has been edited eight (**8**)
>   times by the original owner.

and see [revision 8](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2865675/revisions#rev0d3b2f30-d6d3-42a8-9b6c-e50fdf500464) of that post

> **8**      pronoun; [made Community Wiki]

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that.